# Routing navtabs with bootstrap and python

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to implement navigation via navtab in pythone and flask.

> index.html

I have a link

```
<a href="/getSites">Sites</a>
```

When I click on the link "getSites", I bring to the apache.html page that containing the navtabs and the content of first tab:

> apache.html

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sites[which calls the "getSites" function]">Sites</a></li> 
    <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#modules[which calls the "getModules" function]">Modules</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#configurations[which calls the "getConfig" function]">Configurations</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="sites" class="tab-pane fade in active">
     <h3 class="title">Sites</h3>
     [...] [result of "getSites"]
  </div>
  <div id="modules" class="tab-pane fade">
     <h3 class="title">Modules</h3>
     [...] [result of "getModules"]
  </div>
  <div id="configurations" class="tab-pane fade">
     <h3 class="title">Configurations</h3>
     [...] [result of "getConfig"]
  </div>
```

How can I navigate this navbar, so that I report the results in the bottom div?

Can you help me?
I use python, flask, bootstrap3, jquery and javascript.

Comment: Have you included the [Bootstrap JS file](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)?

Comment: Yes, of course. Why?

Comment: There should be a `data-target` attribute on each of your `li` elements pointing to each `div` respectively, IIRC.